# PHP, HTML, jQuery website file- and code structure

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, structure

I'm quite new to web developement and I'm working on a school project where I am to create a simple educational video platform. My upcomming task is to make my site a single page application. From what I've gathered, jQuery and AJAX will make this happen. While browsing examples and tutorials about these languages, I'm starting to wonder if my HTML/PHP/Script code structure needs to change. Picture contains the typical structure of my files.
[image]

I've been writing the PHP and HTML in the same .php file for each job the site has to do (e.g. upload video form data). I've included all of these in my main.php file. To make it a single page application, **will I need to separate HTML and PHP from each include file, into different files?** Also I'd like some feedback (opinions) on how I've structured this so far.

Comment: seeing the image i realize that you are using most of php code in `HTML` page . Here is a better way you can use `PHP Objects and Classes`. You just need to create a class , then include class and create its object in main  page where you use lot of `Mark up language`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The high-level of what you want to do is move your php logic out of your html files. Here's how a single-page app should handle data flow:

1. In file.HTML: forms and fields take user input (anything from text to files)
2. In file.JS: You use jQuery to listen for events that are happening, essentially using your page's dom elements to pass dynamically entered data to your server through AJAX calls
3. In controller.php: The ajax call goes to a method in one of your controller files where all your logic will happen, items will be added to your database, etc.
4. In file.JS: The ajax call finishes by receiving data from your controller method, and makes the necessary changes to your view file (again using jQuery)
5. In file.html: The jQuery updates show a user the results of their input

The big change to make is separating your php and html files. Since you're doing a single-page application, you can probably get away with one html file, but you should have generally have a controller for every class (assuming you are using class and model interchangeably).

One thing that also might be missing is routes, though I've seen people getting by passing files as the 'url' field (a required field when making an AJAX call).

As far as file structure, most web frameworks will pair cs and js folders into a parent folder called public.

When it comes to jQuery, this is the [best cheat sheet](https://oscarotero.com/jquery) around. Make sure you have at least a basic understanding of the dom before going in too deep though.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to learn about MVC pattern

you can start here 
[The MVC Pattern and PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/)